# How to renew ITIN? How often it gets expired?

Tags: united-states, taxes, itin

Last year my spouse applied for ITIN and it was received around September. This year, when I filed my taxes (jointly) via HR block software, I got an automated email from HR block saying that `you or someone listed on your 2020 return has an ITIN that expired`. I used my SSN so it's definitely for my spouse. I called the place from where I applied for the ITIN first time last year, and they asked for the middle two numbers from the ITIN and mentioned that that sequence is set to expire towards the end of this year.

1. I want to know is it easy enough to renew it on my own and don't seek any tax professional help?
2. Is it going to expire every year and I have to renew it every year?

Comment: Something is off here. Did you (your spouse) apply last year _with a 2019 return_ or separately? If you applied for and got an ITIN for use on a 2019 return it definitely should not expire in 2020; in fact it should not expire if used on any return in 3 (consecutive) years. And the expiration based on middle two digits should only apply to ITINs issued before 2013, which yours wasn't. See https://www.irs.gov/individuals/itin-expiration-faqs . I'm not sure how a 'tax professional' is involved, unless they are _also_ a Certifying Acceptance Agent ('Certified' in the FAQ is wrong).

Comment: I see. I got married in early 2020 so for 2019, I filed my taxes as single with my SSN.  In the link you mentioned, I do see that my spouse's ITIN's middle digit is listed under here `Those with middle digits 90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98 or 99`.  Thanks for the info. I used the certified IRS agent (listed on IRS website) to apply for ITIN last year and wondering why IRS issued an ITIN which is set to expire this year.

Comment: Also, I just used my spouse'ss ITIN to file jointly. There isn't any type of income reported from my spouse's side since I am the only one earning in my family and after reading some of the Q&A on the website, it is making me believe that it might not be needed to renew the ITIN.

Answer (score -1):

Filing jointly (vs. filing single) can reduce your tax bill significantly. It seems prudent for your spouse to renew the ITIN, to allow you to continue to file jointly in the future. Use [Form W-7](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-w-7) "to renew an existing ITIN that is expiring or that has already expired."